# No bluez device after pactl list sources short

Tags: raspberry-pi, pulseaudio, bluetooth, debian

I am using pulseaudio on a Raspberry Debian (Wheezy) but my bt-headset(Iqua BHS-611) does not show up in sources or sinks.

**What I did:**

I followed the *Raspbian Wheezy Installation Guide* at: http://kmonkey711.blogspot.de/2012/12/a2dp-audio-on-raspberry-pi.html

Having entered:

```
pactl list sources short
```

I only get the following but no bluez device.

```
0       alsa_output.platform-bcm2835_AUD0.0.analog-stereo.monitor       module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
```

Instead of the command `bluez-simple-agent` I used `hcitool scan` which showed my device:

```
bluez-test-device trusted <MAC> yes
```

This appeared to work as well but still no bt-devices.

Comment: Don't everybody speak up at once.

Answer (score 1):

`hcitool` only scan for bluetooth device nearby. It does not associate with a bluetooth device. To see it's audio source, you need to pair with the bluetooth device. This can be done using `bluez-simple-agent`, as noted in your source.